# Vertical curved timeline

Tags: css, svg, timeline

How can i achieve a vertical curved timeline as shown in the drawing below? The circles are images and the rectangles div elements. The circles are connected with a horizontal line to the timeline and a dot on the timeline. Is this possible? Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Additional information: it will be added to a WP website. So svg would probably not be the best option?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by putting borders on the div elements on the sides of the images and then a radius to have it curved. Solution came to me when eating a herring sandwich. Try it, it's the best. Enjoy your meal :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).